# Python - Browser closes request before script has completed

Tags: python-3.x, api

I am trying to write a script which returns some output after processing. If there is no processing, the program works fine. e.g. the following code works fine in console and browser.

```
print("Content-Type: text/html\n")
print("Hello world!")
```

But, if I do some processing like fetching a web page, and then print some output, the browser (or API service like Postman) does not show it. The following code works fine in console, but only outputs "Hello" in the browser.

```
print("Content-Type: text/html\n")
print("Hello") 
# Do some processing (fetch a web page)
print("World)
```

It looks like the browser terminates the request when there is a delay. How do I fix this?

Comment: If you do `print("Content-Type: application/json\n")`, the output will be shown in the terminal, not in the browser. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @ForceBru: Edited the question for clarity.

Comment: Note that `print()` automatically appends a newline, so your two examples do not do the same thing.